# Use fetch to get configuration from a symfony rest api fails, but why?

Tags: rest, symfony

I've created new react application (using create-react-app). First thing I've made is "fetch" instruction to get information from symfony rest api.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/company')
    .then((res) => (function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.text().then(function(text) {
            return text ? JSON.parse(text) : {}
        })
    }))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    this.state = {
        company: 'Company name'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2># {this.state.company}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I just need to get information from api and update application state.

[image: no description]

But this in the only result I got.

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable Cors on your rest API, or your both apps have to be on the same domain.

Cors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Basically, you just have to add cors headers to your endpoints.

You can check this great bundle for Symfony:
https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

or if you are not in control of that rest api, you can use some chrome extension that will disable cors.